# Reloading /etc/ld.so.preload without starting a new shell

Tags: linux, shell

I'm adding a preload library using `/etc/ld.so.preload`. My problem is, it doesn't take effect until a new shell is created. This also happens if I remove the preload library. I get error messages for the missing library until I load a new shell.

So, my question is, **How can I force a reload of `/etc/ld.so.preload`?** I looked a the man pages and can't find anything describing the mechanism of when or how it is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a library to the /etc/ld.so.preload file, it specifies that the dynamic linker should load that library before any other library. This means that when you execute a program, the specified library will be loaded before any other libraries that the program depends on.

However, once the preload library has been loaded, it remains in memory until the process that loaded it terminates. This means that if you remove the library from /etc/ld.so.preload, it will not be removed from memory until the process that loaded it terminates. Similarly, if you add a library to /etc/ld.so.preload, it will not take effect until a new process is created.

To force the dynamic linker to reload the libraries specified in /etc/ld.so.preload, you can use the command:

```
sudo ldconfig -v -n /etc/ld.so.preload
```

This command will reload the libraries specified in /etc/ld.so.preload and other configuration files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/. The -v flag is used to print the output of the command to the console, and the -n flag is used to specify the directory containing the configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Might be this is not the answer to your question but consider as alternative.

You can try using below.

```
$ LD_PRELOAD="<colon separated .so path which might be in your ld.so.preload>" <your command>
```

Example:

```
LD_PRELOAD="/mypath1/myso1.so:/mypath2/myso2.so" ls -lh
```